# Google Oauth 2.0 authentication for limited input device not working except on curl

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, android-youtube-api

I am trying to use a custom java application of mine to upload videos to my youtube account via an access limited device like a Raspberry pi running as a server.

For this I am using the [Google Oauth 2.0 for limited input device](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#devices) as a reference.

I followed the steps mentioned with my custom java application, [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), the surprise is as follows:

1. All of the calls worked right as mentioned by [Google Oauth 2.0 for limited input device](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#devices) for curl.
2. But issues were observed with Fiddler and my custom java app for the following call:

When I am trying to get the access token from Google server (Step 4 from Google Oauth link) by posting similar request:

> ```
> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1    
> Host: accounts.google.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
> client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSem&
> code=4/YMSlR3fSCC1NtUh073DuZKTJJ3ss&
> grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0
> ```

**but instead of getting the 'access_token' as response I am getting the following :**

> ```
> Status Code:400 Response: {   "error" : "invalid_request", 
> "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" }
> ```

**Note :** With or without url encoding, my problem stays the same.

**I am unable to understand what the issue is with my custom java app or with fiddler, Please help.**

**Following are my fiddler requests:**

(One can get oauth credentials (client_id and client_secret) by following [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application))

Fiddler request:
(url encoded, obscured client secret)

```
POST HTTP/1.1
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=308065994473-ur9dd7003ajs6mvr5s4kqnugr6j8tsf2.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=4%2FWR-qiTquqB0e4-0LCy0-7rZ2kkE2&grant_type=http%3A%2F%2Foauth.net%2Fgrant_type%2Fdevice%2F1.0

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

(non url encoded, obscured client secret)

```
POST HTTP/1.1
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=308065994473-ur9dd7003ajs6mvr5s4kqnugr6j8tsf2.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=4/WR-qiTquqB0e4-0LCy0-7rZ2kkE2&grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0
```

**Java code project is available at (maven project, check the test case for the Oauth calls):**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ltWBtPF-DVMDZFNHNMZXpCQlk

Comment: Please show your fiddler request and java code.

Comment: You java code is wrong, I've edit it as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters need to be added in the http post request body not in the url, Google documentation is confusing on this part.

```
    public synchronized HttpResponse executePOST(HttpEntity httpEntity, String path) throws IOException {
    if (!parameters.isEmpty()) {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
    }

    httpPost = new HttpPost(path);

    logger.info(target.toHostString());
    logger.info(httpPost.getURI().toString());
    logger.info(httpPost.getRequestLine().toString());
    for (Header header : headers) {
        logger.info(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
        httpPost.addHeader(header);
    }
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(target, httpPost);
    return httpResponse;
}
```